# How to design corresponding class hierarchies (e.g. mirroring hierarchies in client/server context)?

Tags: c++, tree, client-server, polymorphism, class-design

I am looking for options for implementing the following situation:

In a client/server system, I want to implement an infrastructure that evaluates expressions that are constructed on the client side. The expressions shall be represented by an expression tree, encoded in something like XML for communication. On the client side, there shall be a UI for composing the tree and editing existing trees. On the server side, there shall be an infrastructure for evaluating the trees and for storage and retrieval of such trees.

The storage/retrieval part is simple. It's just about storing a piece of text inside a DB.

Now, for the composing/editing UI and for the evaluation logic, I need on both the client and the server side a corresponding class hierarchy of expression classes which will be used to represent the expression tree. The tree will be built from the textual representation and will be used to produce a textual representation. On the server side, strictly, only the parsing part, not the production of the textual representation is needed. But in principle, that part can be shared between client and server code. (The parser utilizes a registry of available expression classes for constructing appropriate nodes.)

On the client side, the tree needs to be processed for updating an evaluating GUI state. On the server side, the tree needs to be processed for evaluating the expression.

So, one option that I see is writing distinct tree visitors on client and server side, e.g. for updating GUI state, evaluating GUI state and for evaluation the expression. The draw-back is that I cannot use virtual methods for treating the polymorphism of the expressions but instead need to hard-code the different existing expression sub-classes into dynamically casting code in the visitors.

The option that I would favor more is to put the expression actions (updating GUI, evaluating GUI, evaluation the expression) into the interface of the expression base class. However, the server side shall not contain any GUI code. Conversely, the expression evaluation depends on server infrastructure such that it cannot be compiled with the client code obviously. So, there is no common base class for expressions to be shared between client and server if the expression actions are part of the interface.

I am currently thinking of whether it is possible to make the expression class hierarchy a template of the per-expression interface but I think, it might be interesting to hear suggestions from the stackoverflow community at the same time.

Implementation context: C++/Qt

Comment: you could perhaps create a class or struct to handle all the variables required and then pass them over the network, that way the package is the common link and neither side need to be aware of the class specifics of the classes which generate the variables.